# Can question 307725 please be reopened

Tags: support, reopen-request

I am a little confused. I think my question [307725](https://superuser.com/questions/307725/how-do-i-send-documents-to-my-kindle-for-android-and-windows-apps-if-i-dont-actu) was incorrectly closed by a moderator.

The question refers to the use of the Kindle app on Windows. Surely that is acceptable?

Answer (score 8):

You may be wanting it for a desktop app, but the whole crux of your question is stated as:

> The problem is that I don't own a Kindle so how do I find out what my Kindle [name] is?

This is an Amazon support issue and not on topic for Super User.